# How to map interaction events to game actions

Tags: design-patterns, events, porting, user-interface

When I port between Desktop games and Mobile games, I find I always make a kludge out of the interaction events.

I typically end up hard-coding event handling for mobile, and event handling for the desktop in completely separate systems.

On mobile, I need to track multiple touches.

On desktop, I only have a single mouse pointer.

But on desktop, there is a concept of "hovering" above something with a mouse.
There is no such thing on mobile.
Or pressing a modifier key like SHIFT or CTRL while clicking a button or pressing a key.

I want to design an **API** that I can use on both mobile and desktop that is able to translate an interaction (by user) to an action in my game world.

Are there any **design patterns** that I can follow, or some **abstract model** I can use for this? How do people successfully marry the desktop and mobile port of a game?

So in the same code-base, maybe assign Alt+Left-Click to a certain game function, but on mobile have that done via a gesture.

On Desktop, I currently use SDL2's [SDL_Event](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event). On Apple, is use [UIEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uievent?language=objc), and on Android I use NDK's [AInputEvent](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/input).

Comment: This is kind of a link and opinion based question/answer, so idk if it's appropriate to answer it in `answers`. I would suggest going with `Command` pattern and mapping different input types to commands. Then if possible is to have a `platform-dependent compilation` to avoid having `if`s for every type of device input.